# MarkLogic 8 - node.js API - Convert XML to JSON

Tags: node.js, xquery, marklogic

I am working learning the Javascript API for MarkLogic.

I do a query:

```
cts.search(
  cts.andQuery(
    [cts.wordQuery("abc"), cts.collectionQuery(["Strings"])]
  )
);
```

And get XML. I know how to convert this XML to JSON in XQuery, but how do I do it in Node? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is available in external modules. I've used [`xml2js`](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) and never had a problem, so I can recommend that.

Once you've installed the module (`npm install --save xml2js`), you can do something like this:

```
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
var xml = "<root>Hello xml2js!</root>"
parseString(xml, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

Comment: Oh I was looking for a MarkLogic library, but I just had the revelation that now that I'm working on using the node API instead of XQuery, I don't need to rely on their libraries anymore.

Now I can use the full power of npm.